# Augmented Reality fluid camera movement

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, core-motion

I have an Augmented Reality view based on SceneKit and CoreMotion. Camera orientation is updated at 60 fps using CMDeviceMotion value. This works fine, but I would like to have more fluid movement. An example is application SkyView Free. There when you rapidly rotate the phone, AR camera is rotated rapidly, but not instantly, giving more fluid experience. It is like animating its rotation instead just rotating to current value instantly. How can I achieve similar effect? I was thinking about lowering device motion FPS to about 4-5 and then using SCNAction with duration about 0.2, but I don't think I can use SCNAction to animate orientation change of node. Or can I?

Comment: How can you say that movement after small delay is more fluid than instant movement according to the real rotation ? It has no sense to be honest. In terms of AR every delay is killing the fluid experience

Comment: I think that there is a problem with small errors in readings from core motion, making movement jittering sometimes. Anyway I think I have found the answer - applying low pass filter with small factor like 0.2 is making this work similar to the app I have mentioned. Delay is very small, almost not visible, and no jittering is visible.

Comment: yes, spikes, jittering is a common case when you are trying to pass sensor readings to the camera motion. Low pass filter is one of the tools, you can also use Kalman filter when you`re refering to the GPS readings. It won't fix it in 100% (trust me you will have spikes) but often it is enough :)